# Binding Child to parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am novice in WPF and wanted to know how in WPF can we bind the child to parent. To make it more clear: I have an user-control like

```
<Button x:Name="JobViewer" Margin="5" Background="Transparent" Content="{TemplateBinding Content }" ToolTip="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Black">
                <Border CornerRadius="8" Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Left="-52" Canvas.Top="-50"
                BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" Opacity=".6" ShadowDepth="2" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Update" CornerRadius="20" Width="35" Height="38" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="-65" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=JobViewerUpdateVisibility}"BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" RenderTransformOrigin="1.346,-0.919">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" Opacity=".6" ShadowDepth="2" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource StateCompletedIcon}"></Image>
                </Border>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Now in content in the button I want to use template Binding so that I can use this user control in XAML Window and set the content property of the Button and that image will be set as image source for the first image?
If some one has other idea to achieve it please share that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the `Button`'s `Content` with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`. In this example I used a simple `Style` for the `Button` instead of a `UserControl`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="Black">
                    <Border CornerRadius="8" Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Left="-52" Canvas.Top="-50" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" Opacity=".6" ShadowDepth="2" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="Update" CornerRadius="20" Width="35" Height="38" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="-65" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" RenderTransformOrigin="1.346,-0.919">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" Opacity=".6" ShadowDepth="2" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource StateCompletedIcon}"></Image>
                    </Border>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Button Content="C:\Whatever.png"/>
```

or

```
<Button Content="pack://application:,,,/Whatever.png"/>
```

Result:

[image: Example Button with Style]